# how to get data from parse.com and set them on text field?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

[Swift] Coders

Can someone explain how can i get data from parse.com to set them on text field? i've did a query but isn't working:

```
var currentuser = PFUser.currentUser().username
var query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
query.whereKey("username", equalTo: currentuser)

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [AnyObject] !, error: NSError ? ) - > Void in
    if error == nil {
        for object in objects {
            self.usernamearray.append(object["username"] as String!)
        }
    }
}
textfield.text = usernamearray // ???? how to do that
```

I'm trying to get current user "username" and show it on text field, i'm waiting help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
textfield.text = usernamearray[0]
```

Your code appears to be using a username that you're returning. You can just use:

```
if let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() {

    textfield.text = currentUser.username
}
```

**Update:**

```
var currentuser = PFUser.currentUser().username
var query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
query.whereKey("username", equalTo: currentuser)

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {

    (objects: [AnyObject]!, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            for object in objects {

            println(object) //only for debugging 

                self.usernamearray.append(object["username"] as String!)
                textfield.text = usernamearray[0]
             }
         }
}
```

Update 2:
**General Parse.com Example**

Parse.com example:

[image]

Example view controller: 
(In this view controller I am retrieving multiple objects and setting the view controller's text fields for each one, there are other PFQueries, including just fetching a first object or retrieving an object by it's Id)

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class SOTestViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var venueName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var venuePhone: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var venueAddress: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func fetchVenuesFromParse() {

    let queryVenues = PFQuery(className: "Venues") // my example class on Pasre.com

    // I want to get all Venue objects
    queryVenues.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (foundObjects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        // Things that happen inside of these {} happen in the background and may take some time to update from Parse.com

        for foundObject in foundObjects as! [PFObject] { // foundObjects needs to be cast back into PFObjects

            // Access each row on Parse as a foundObject inside this for loop

            //Just for an example, update this view controller's text fields from the data from Parse.com

            self.venueName.text      = foundObject["name"] as! String //Use subscripting on the foundObject and set the type of data
            self.venuePhone.text     = foundObject["phone"] as! String
            self.venueAddress.text   = foundObject["address"] as! String

        }

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but i got errors i did `textfield.text = usernamearray[0]` but i got this output error "fatal error: cannot index empty buffer " and i did `if let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() {

    textfield.text = currentUser.username
}` i got this error : String does not have a member named 'username' , `Please any help?`

Comment: You have to put textfield.text = usernamearray[0] inside the completion handler (the block) of findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock

Comment: updated and if you want to use the if let you have to make sure you're referencing the correct username variable

Comment: I did but the text field is empty! can you please make a quick query which i can get any information from parse to show them on text field?

Comment: You need to make sure that the query returned a result, add a println statement to verify your results. The query that is in the answer is adequate for what you want to get. Added a print statement in the for loop to see if an object was returned (will show in your console output)

Comment: I did println(object) , but nothing showing on output, what's that mean ? or what's wrong

Comment: Your query isn't returning any results, you should make sure there is a PFUser logged in

Comment: I believe i already logged in, Could you please make another example how to get nickname from class "_User" and show it on text field ?

Comment: Remove the code that you have and just use my first if let example

Comment: Yes it worked! but i want to get other data from parse like nickname , etc! how to do that ?

Comment: I'm glad it worked, you should mark the answer as correct so others know it can help them. Your second question is broad and it depends on how you setup parse. I suggest following this tutorial to learn more about using Parse.com with Swift: http://www.appcoda.com/instagram-app-parse-swift/

Comment: it worked but that is not what i want, i still confused on how to get data from parse and show them on text field, I really appreciate that you tried to help me !

Comment: I have added a 2nd more general code example but still suggest you complete some parse.com & swift tutorials

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I've fixed my problem! I really appreciate it, I hope you'll get a happy life!